# Extend texture beyond limits

Tags: texturing, faces

Is it possible to add an image texture to a face of a solid but instead of clipping the image to shape and size of the face to go out of bounds? For example like in the image, apply to the triangular face a texture image that goes out of bounds.

[image]

I would like to have tangent images snapped to each of the faces showing that those images are the ones that eventually are going to contribute to the content of that face. Something like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Image Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html) node has 3 *Extension* modes:

[image]

Extension defines how the image is extrapolated past the original bounds:

**Repeat:** Will repeat the image horizontally and vertically giving tiled-looking result.

**Extend:** Will extend the image by repeating pixels on its edges.

**Clip:** Clip to the original image size and set all the exterior pixels values to transparent black.

---

Edit: perhaps could be done with instancing planes on mesh faces, but in order for textures to match you would have to calculate UV space yourself from the instancer's object coordinate system. If additionally you would like to unwrap the instancer in a usual way, you probably would have to bake some translation of world space normal to UV position...

Perhaps an easier and more dynamic (no need for baking) solution could be done with geometry nodes, but I still haven't learned these nodes.

What I know is Python, so here's a Python solution - select a few faces and run the script:

[image]

```py
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
uvm = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
for old_face in bm.select_history:
    tip = sorted(old_face.loops, key=lambda l: l.vert.co.z)[-1]  # highest vertex
    base0 = tip.link_loop_next
    base1 = base0.link_loop_next
    offset = (base1.vert.co - base0.vert.co) / 2
    off_uv = (base1[uvm].uv - base0[uvm].uv) / 2
    coords = [base0.vert.co, base1.vert.co, tip.vert.co + offset, tip.vert.co - offset]
    cos_uv = [base0[uvm].uv, base1[uvm].uv, tip[uvm].uv + off_uv, tip[uvm].uv - off_uv]
    verts = [bm.verts.new(co) for co in coords]
    new_face = bm.faces.new(verts)
    for loop, co in zip(new_face.loops, cos_uv):
        loop[uvm].uv = co
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=[old_face], context='FACES_KEEP_BOUNDARY')
    new_face.select_set(True)  # just so you can visually see no difference inside the (old) triangle

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

**I assumed selected faces are triangles.**

Comment: Hey Thanks for this. My question is other then I guess. How can I see the extended texture in object mode to be rendered? I mean I would like to have a rendering where each face has a "tangent" image associated which contributes to the texture of that face. I will edit my question

Comment: Super useful. Thanks so much!